# CKEditor 4 : How to add custom plugin like word count while building from Angular CKEditor CDN?

Tags: angular, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am using the default CDN of CKEditor angular to use it in my application. However I have a need to limit the number of characters in the editor for which I found this [wordcount](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/wordcount) plugin which is not there in any of CDNs - basic or standard version

How do I add this plugin in my application?

Found this [blog](https://cdn.ckeditor.com/) to add local plugins but unable to make this work. Any suggestions if this is the right way to go about this?

If I add word count in config of angular I get this error

```
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'wordcount' does not exist in type 'config'.



  53             wordcount : {
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    54                 maxCharCount: 100,
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    55             },
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```